# How to share data between two widgets by using Provider?

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I have two widgets which I shared codes below, In first card widget for user selecting ingredients, second card will be used for displaying selected ingrediens, initial both screen will be empty, when user add an igredients both widget will be rebuilt by according to selected ingredients, I could handle it displaying in first widget, but I can not handle to display selectedIngredient list data when it changes, I know I have to use provider packages but I could not implement for my code, I have stuck please help me.. .

```
class AddIngredientsCard extends StatefulWidget {
  AddIngredientsCard({this.subCategoryId,this.subCategoryCardId});
  final int subCategoryCardId;
  final int subCategoryId;
  @override
  _AddIngredientsCardState createState() => _AddIngredientsCardState();
}
class _AddIngredientsCardState extends State<AddIngredientsCard>{
  String textValue;
  double _animatedContainerHeight=350;
  double _top=15;
  double _right=30;
  double _left=30;
  double _bottom=15;
  List<String> items= [];
  List<String>selectedIngredients=[];

  @override
  void initState() {
    ingredients=ingredients..sort((String a, String b)=>a.compareTo(b));
    items.addAll(ingredients);
    super.initState();
  }

  void filterSearchResults(String query) {
    List<String> searchList = [];
    searchList.addAll(ingredients);
    if(query.isNotEmpty) {
      List<String> listData = [];
      searchList.forEach((item) {
        if(item.contains(query)) {
          listData.add(item);
        }
      });
      setState(() {
        items.clear();
        items.addAll(listData);
      });
      return;
    } else {
      setState(() {
        items.clear();
        items.addAll(ingredients);
      });
    }
  }



  void _toggleCardSize(){
    _top==15?_top=7.5: _top=15;
    _right==30?_right=7.5: _right=30;
    _left==30?_left=7.5: _left=30;
    _bottom==15?_bottom=7.5: _bottom=15;
  }

  void _toggleCardHeight(){
    _animatedContainerHeight==350?_animatedContainerHeight=600:_animatedContainerHeight=350;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {


    return AnimatedPadding(
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
      curve: Curves.linearToEaseOut,
      padding:EdgeInsets.only(top: _top,right: _right,left: _left,bottom: _bottom),
      child: AnimatedContainer(
          height:_animatedContainerHeight,
          duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    border:Border.all(style: BorderStyle.solid, width: 1),
                    color: Colors.white,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(90),
                  ),
                  height: 60,
                  child: TextField(
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      fontFamily:"OpenSans",
                      fontSize: 20,
                    ),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.center,
                    onChanged: (value){
                      if(value.length>0){
                        value=value[0].toUpperCase()+value.substring(1);
                        filterSearchResults(value);
                      }
                      else{
                        filterSearchResults(value);
                      }
                    },
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
                      border:OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(90),
                        borderSide: BorderSide(
                          color: kColorTheme10,
                        ),
                      ),
                      hintText: "Malzeme ismi arayın",
                      hintStyle: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5),
                        fontFamily: "OpenSans",
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 2,),
                Expanded(
                  flex: _animatedContainerHeight==350?1:4,
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    itemCount: selectedIngredients.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context,index){
                      return Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(1),
                        child: GestureDetector(
                          onTap: (){
                            setState(() {
                              selectedIngredients.removeAt(index);
                              if (selectedIngredients.length == 0) {
                                _toggleCardHeight();
                                _toggleCardSize();
                                }
                              }
                            );
                          },
                          child: Container(
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: kColorTheme11,
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(90),
                              border: Border.all(style: BorderStyle.solid,width: 1),
                            ),
                            child: Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                              child: Row(
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                children: [
                                  BorderedText(strokeColor: Colors.black,strokeWidth: 5,child: Text(selectedIngredients[index],style:
                                    TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,fontSize:20,color: Colors.white),)),
                                  SizedBox(width: 5,),
                                  Icon(
                                    Icons.cancel,color: Colors.white,size: 20,
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    }
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 2,),
                Expanded(
                  flex: 40,
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    itemCount: items.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
                        child: GestureDetector(
                          onTap: (){
                            setState(() {
                              if(selectedIngredients.length==0){
                                selectedIngredients.add("${items[index]}");
                                _toggleCardHeight();
                                _toggleCardSize();
                              }
                              else{
                                selectedIngredients.add("${items[index]}");
                              }
                            });
                          },
                          child: Container(
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(90),
                              border: Border.all(style:BorderStyle.solid,width: 1),
                              color: Colors.white54,

                            ),
                            child: Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                              child: Text('${items[index]}',style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),)),
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 8,),
                Expanded(
                  flex: _animatedContainerHeight==350?1:4,
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      Expanded(
                        child: Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color:  _animatedContainerHeight==350?categoryModels[widget.subCategoryId].
                            subCategoryModels[widget.subCategoryCardId].categoryColor.withOpacity(0.1):kColorTheme11,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                            border: _animatedContainerHeight==350?null:
                            Border.all(style: BorderStyle.solid,width: 2),
                          ),
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                            child: GestureDetector(
                              onTap: (){
                                AddIngredientsAmount(subCategoryId:widget.subCategoryId,subCategoryCardId: widget.subCategoryId,selectedIngredients: selectedIngredients,);
                                  /////////////////////////////////////// => isPageSaved için Provider eklenecek...
                              },
                              child: Center(child: BorderedText(strokeWidth:3,strokeColor: Colors.black,child:
                              Text("KAYDET",style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25, fontWeight: FontWeight.w900 ,color: Colors.white))),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        )
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border: Border.all(style: BorderStyle.solid, width: 1),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
            color:categoryModels[widget.subCategoryId].subCategoryModels[widget.subCategoryCardId].categoryColor.withOpacity(0.5),
          )
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```
class AddIngredientsAmount extends StatefulWidget {
  AddIngredientsAmount({this.subCategoryId,this.subCategoryCardId, this.selectedIngredients});
  final List selectedIngredients;
  final int subCategoryCardId;
  final int subCategoryId;
  @override
  _AddIngredientsAmountState createState() => _AddIngredientsAmountState();
}
class _AddIngredientsAmountState extends State<AddIngredientsAmount> {
  String textValue;
  double _animatedContainerHeight=300;
  double _top=15;
  double _right=30;
  double _left=30;
  double _bottom=15;


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    void _toggleCardSize(){
      _top==15?_top=7.5: _top=15;
      _right==30?_right=7.5: _right=30;
      _left==30?_left=7.5: _left=30;
      _bottom==15?_bottom=7.5: _bottom=15;
    }

    void _toggleCardHeight(){
      _animatedContainerHeight==300?_animatedContainerHeight=500:_animatedContainerHeight=300;
    }
    return AnimatedPadding(
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
      curve: Curves.linearToEaseOut,
      padding:EdgeInsets.only(top: _top,right: _right,left: _left,bottom: _bottom),
      child: GestureDetector(
          onTap: (){
            setState(() {
              _toggleCardHeight();
              _toggleCardSize();
            });
          },
          child: AnimatedContainer(
              height:_animatedContainerHeight,
              duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        border:Border.all(style: BorderStyle.solid, width: 1),
                        color: Colors.white,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(90))),
                      child: Center(
                        child: Text("Malzemelerinizin Miktarını Belirlerin",style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.black,
                          fontFamily:'OpenSans',
                          fontSize:25,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 7.5,),
                    Expanded(
                      child: Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color:Colors.white,
                          border: Border.all(style: BorderStyle.solid, width: 1),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                        ),
                        child: ListView.builder(
                          itemCount: widget.selectedIngredients.length==null?0:
                            widget.selectedIngredients.length,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index){
                            return Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(2),
                              child: Container(
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(90),
                                  border: Border.all(style:BorderStyle.solid,width: 1),
                                  color: Colors.white54,

                                ),
                                child: Row(
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                  children: [
                                    Padding(
                                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                                        child: Text('${widget.selectedIngredients[index]}',style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,fontSize: 30),)),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            );
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border.all(style: BorderStyle.solid, width: 1),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                color:categoryModels[widget.subCategoryId].subCategoryModels[widget.subCategoryCardId].categoryColor.withOpacity(0.5),
              )
          )
      ),
    );
  }
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------

class AddRecipeVoice extends StatefulWidget {
  AddRecipeVoice({this.subCategoryId,this.subCategoryCardId});
  final int subCategoryCardId;
  final int subCategoryId;
  @override
  _AddRecipeVoiceState createState() => _AddRecipeVoiceState();
}
class _AddRecipeVoiceState extends State<AddRecipeVoice> {
  String textValue;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return AnimatedPadding(
      duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
      curve: Curves.linearToEaseOut,
      padding:EdgeInsets.only(top: 15,left: 30,right: 30,bottom: 7.5),
      child: GestureDetector(
          onTap: (){
            setState(() {
            });
          },
          child: Container(
              height:130,
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          border:Border.all(style: BorderStyle.solid, width: 1),
                          color: Colors.white,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(90))),
                      child: Center(
                        child: Text("Tarifinizi anlatın",style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.black,
                          fontFamily:'OpenSans',
                          fontSize:25,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                        ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 7.5,),
                    Expanded(
                      child: GestureDetector(
                        child: Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color:kColorTheme7,
                            border: Border.all(style: BorderStyle.solid, width: 1),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                          ),
                          child: Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: [
                              Icon(Icons.mic,size: 40,color: Colors.white,),
                              SizedBox(width: 50,),
                              Text(
                                "KAYIT ZAMANI !!",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 30,
                                  fontFamily: "OpenSans",
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border.all(style: BorderStyle.solid, width: 1),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                color:categoryModels[widget.subCategoryId].subCategoryModels[widget.subCategoryCardId].categoryColor.withOpacity(0.5),
              )
          )
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Make a provider class that mixin with ChangeNotifier.
2. Wrap your widget prior calling the provider class with MultiProvider widget. Likewise:

```
    MultiProvider (
       providers: [
       ChangeNotifierProvider.value(value: IngredientsProvider()),
       ],
       child: YourWidget(), //You can wrap your MaterialApp here
    )
```

3. Create your needed methods that changes the selected data and call `notifyListeners()` inside your method. It will rebuild your desired widget where you listen to them.

Example:

```
 class IngredientsProvider with ChangeNotifier {
    List<String> _selectedIngredients = [];
    
    List<String> get selectedIngredients() {
        return _selectedIngredients;
    }

    void addIngredient(String ingredient) {
        _selectedIngredients.add(ingredient);
        notifyListeners();
    }
}
```

In your widget listen to them:

```
   Widget1 {

   //Call this in you onPress/onTap
   void addIngredient(String ing, BuildContext ctx) {
        Provider.of<IngredientsProvider>(ctx, listen: 
        false).addIngredient(ing);
   }
   ........ 
   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        //Use this list to select
        List<String> _ingredients = Provider.of<IngredientsProvider>(context, listen: 
        true).ingredients;
    }
   ........ 

}
```

Use in the 2nd Widget in this way.

```
   Widget2 {
   ........ 
   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        //Use this list to show
        List<String> _ingredients = Provider.of<IngredientsProvider>(context, listen: 
        true).ingredients;

    }
   ........ 

}
```